# Is there a way to view tags with no definitions?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I'm fairly active on UX StackExchange and have noticed a lot of tags on the site with no definition.  I'd like to volunteer to clean up some of this, but I can't find a decent way to query tags with no definitions on ux.stackexchange.com

Is this a view available to users?

I've tried [googling](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS542US542&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackexchange%20query%20tags%20with%20no%20definitions) and [querying here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%2Btags%20%2Bundefined) on stackexchange meta but haven't found an answer.

thanks?

Comment: Well, I would've clicked "tags", and select and did some cleaning to the last pages. Don't find it *that* compelling. Do the tags you look for hide themselves somehow? :)

Comment: Thanks all, it appears I was just searching for the wrong terms.